# Why are images not showing on apk after expo build:android? (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, expo

I created an app (using React Native Expo) that has some images like:

`<Image source={require('../assets/facebook_button.png')} />`

The images are in the assets directory and I can see them using the `npm publish` or the `npm start` functionalities.

The problem is when building the app with `exp build:android`, now the apk is **not** showing the static images (but some other images I'm loading from the Internet are being showed).

This is my app.json:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-interesting-app",
    "description": "My Interesting App",
    "slug": "my-interesting-app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "29.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*",
      "assets/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myinteresting.myinterestingapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myinteresting.myinterestingapp"
    },
    
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You resolved this issue? I'm facing the same now...

Comment: @crazy1337 Not yet :/ I was so stucked I decided to fetch the images from a server

Comment: I was able to load the images locally. I've to cache them and then display the image. I've add here as an answer, hope this will help you :)

Comment: Trying fix a problem with assets not being available on Android (ExpoKit v31.0.0). My solution for image is to convert them to Base64 strings. I don't yet have a solution for fonts, can't stringify them or load over http.

Answer (score 6):

Try to cache the image before loading.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, AppLoading } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={() => this._cacheResourcesAsync()}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png')} />
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png')} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  async _cacheResourcesAsync() {
    return Asset.loadAsync([
      require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png'),
      require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

References:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading.html#app-loading
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/asset.html#expoassetloadasyncmodules