# expo build:android not showing images

Tags: javascript, expo

Expo diagnostics outpout :

```
 Expo CLI 4.3.4 environment info:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
Binaries:
  Node: 14.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  npm: 6.14.11 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
npmPackages:
  expo: ^40.0.1 => 40.0.1
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2
  react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
  react-navigation: ^4.4.4 => 4.4.4
Expo Workflow: managed
```

I’m facing an issue with expo build:android command as the resulting build doesn’t show any of the images, but all of them are visible when I use the expo start command.

Here’s what I’ve tried to solve it.

```
<image :source="require('~/assets/images/logo.png')" />
<image :source="require('../../assets/images/logo.png')" />
```

And also another thing I’ve noticed is that if I change the splash screen backgroundColor property the build fails. Below color code doesn’t work

```
"backgroundColor": "#25c16f"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686444/why-are-images-not-showing-on-apk-after-expo-buildandroid-react-native Have a look to this one.

Comment: @flipps this didn't worked as well.